Syntax to replicate the wooCommerce Order Number into the Orders Received Checkout page
The woo Order Number is already display near the top of the Order Received page, just below the "Your order has been received ..." line.
Most of our customer pay using the 'Direct Bank Transfer'(aka "BACs" payment method).
The instructions ask the customer to reuse the Order Number as the 'Reference field' i.e. when they enter the details into their bank's system.  But we would like to improve upon this by replicating the Order Number into a (newly created)'Reference' field when we display our Bank details. e.g.
 BANK:      SORT CODE:  ACCOUNT NUMBER:   REFERENCE:   IBAN:  BIC:  
 myBank     00-00-00    12345678          9876         T1234  ...    ...

We have the working code (shown below) to display the BACs details, but have not found the correct syntax to insert the woo Order Number  (with it's prefixed one character of text.)
add_filter('woocommerce_bacs_account_fields','custom_bacs_fields');

function custom_bacs_fields() {
global $wpdb;
$account_details = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts',
array(
   array(
    'account_name'   => get_option( 'account_name' ),
    'sort_code'      => get_option( 'sort_code' ),
    'bank_name'      => get_option( 'bank_name' ),
    'account_number' => get_option( 'account_number' ),
    'iban'           => get_option( 'iban' ),
    'bic'            => get_option( 'bic' )
   )
)
);

$account_fields = array(
'bank_name'      => array(
    'label' => 'Bank',
    'value' => $account_details[0]['bank_name']
),
'sort_code' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Sort Code', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['sort_code']
),
'account_number' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Account Number', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['account_number']
),
'ref' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Ref', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => 'qwerty' //  $order[0]->get_order_number()  << syntax for this needed
),  
    
'iban' => array(
    'label' => __( 'iban', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['iban']
),
'bic' => array(
    'label' => __( 'bic', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['bic']
)
);
 return $account_fields;
}

-------------------- 2nd attempt --------------------
As suggested,  I tried passing the Order number into the function, and then I printed it to understand its contents:
add_filter('woocommerce_bacs_account_fields','custom_bacs_fields');

function custom_bacs_fields( $order ) {
   print_r( $order );
   //$order_id  = $order->get_id(); // Get the order ID
global $wpdb;
...

But it printed as the BACs array!!:   (where have I gone wrong?)

Array ( [bank_name] => Array ( [label] => Bank [value] => MyBank ) [account_number] => Array ( [label] => Account number [value] => 01234567 ) [sort_code] => Array ( [label] => Sort code [value] => 00-00-00 ) [iban] => Array ( [label] ... etc. etc. ) )


How are the orders table and the bank details table currently associated? Is there a field in the orders table that links to the bank table?

I don't know how their underlying entities are linked.  But the page is displayed immediately the customer places the order .... and the Direct Bank Transfer info comes from Woo>>Settings>>payments methods>>Direct Bank Transfer method.   An example of the page can be see in Section 2 of this page:  https://aovup.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page-hooks/
The Bank Transfer details are not shown on the example, but are immediately below the bit shown.

This page has an example that shows more: https://blog.hostonnet.com/how-to-enable-bank-transfer-payment-in-woocommerce

Take a look at this Try passing the $order as a parameter to your function.  You then may be able to do this $order->get_order_number()

The hook callback function can get an array of fields, and the order ID, passed as parameters. https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_bacs_account_fields That order ID is likely to be the database row ID though, so you'll need to use that to fetch the actual order instance, and then you can call get_order_number on it.

I passed the $order_id using: "function custom_bacs_fields($order_id) {..."   then used:  print_r($order_id); to see the contents before moving on.    But it printed: "Array ( [bank_name] => Array ( [label] => Bank [value] => MyBank ) [account_number] => Array ( [label] => Account number [value] => 01234567 ) [sort_code] => Array ( [label] => Sort code [value] => 00-00-00 ) [iban] => Array ( [label] => IBAN [value] => -redacted- ) [bic] => Array ( [label] => BIC [value] => -redacted ) )"   I'm totally confused ;!

Please see 2nd attempt - which I've added to my original question.

This is the solution that works:  (added to our child php file)
add_filter('woocommerce_bacs_account_fields','custom_bacs_fields');

function custom_bacs_fields( $new_order_id ) {
    global $new_order_id;       // needs to be global, defined earlier when 'P' prefixed to the Order No.,
        //  debug_to_console( $new_order_id );
    global $wpdb;
$account_details = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts',
array(
   array(
    'account_name'   => get_option( 'account_name' ),
    'sort_code'      => get_option( 'sort_code' ),
    'bank_name'      => get_option( 'bank_name' ),
    'account_number' => get_option( 'account_number' ),
    'iban'           => get_option( 'iban' ),
    'bic'            => get_option( 'bic' ),
   )
)
);

$account_fields = array(
'bank_name'      => array(
    'label' => 'Bank',
    'value' => $account_details[0]['bank_name']
),

'sort_code' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Sort Code', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['sort_code']
),

'account_number' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Account Number', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['account_number']
),
    
'ref' => array(
    'label' => __( 'Reference', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $new_order_id    
),  
    
'iban' => array(
    'label' => __( 'iban', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' =>  $account_details[0]['iban']
),
    
'bic' => array(
    'label' => __( 'bic', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => $account_details[0]['bic']
),
);
 return $account_fields;
} 

/* end of function   */

